# Help with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is the code that I have in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^tamil/(.*)/(.*).html?$ http://www.mywebsite.org/download.php?q=$2&id=$1
```

So when I go to:

```
http://www.mywebsite.org/tamil/465/man.html
```

It should go to:

```
http://www.mywebsite.org/download.php?q=man&id=465
```

This works perfectly. The problem is after redirecting, the URL in the address bar is:

```
http://www.mywebsite.org/download.php?q=man&id=465
```

However, I need the source URL to be displayed in the address bar:

```
http://www.mywebsite.org/tamil/465/man.html
```

Please give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^tamil/([^/]*)/([^\.]*)\.html$ /download.php?q=$2&id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: One thing you have to make sure on SO if you want people to assist you, you also have to assist them by providing some details. Merely `not working` doesn't give my any info what's not working. btw above rule when I deployed on my Apache forwards a URI of `/tamil/465/man.html` to `/download.php?q=man&id=465`. Now may I know what's not working? Paste your access.log, error.log and your sample test case here if possible.